# react - map through spesific array depends on the url

Tags: reactjs

i want to create a website which inside you have 2 categories -
USA and EUROPE, if you click EUROPE it takes you to a new URL which inside will be a component that maps through some europe countries.
the thing is i want to use the same component to map both usa or europe, but depends on what you clicked it will show you the correct array
so in code it will be something like

```
export const DATA = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "europe",
    countries: [
        {
            id: 1,
            coutry: "frence"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            coutry: "germany"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "USA",
    countries: [
        {
            id: 1,
            coutry: "NYC"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            coutry: "LA"
        }
    ]
}];
```

and on the homepage we will have something like:

```
 this.state.lands.map( ({ id, title}) => (
                    <LandCard key={id} title={title}  />
```

LandCard component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./land-card.styles.scss";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const LandCard = ({ title, image, history, linkUrl, match }) => {

return(
<div className="card-container" onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}${linkUrl}`)}>

    <div
     className="background-image"
     style={{
         backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
     }}
    >
        <h1>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
        
    </div>
</div>
)
}
export default withRouter(LandCard);
```

lets say that clicking europe will take you to a url localhost:3000/europe,
how can i use that to take us to a new page that will show the "countries" array of europe only?
but i want to use THE SAME mapping component for both USA and EUROPE, and the component will show the countries depends on what you clicked.
i guess i will need to use react-router-dom?

i know its a lot to ask really hope you can help

Comment: Could you please add your `LandCard` component?

Comment: Actually, there are 2 components. First where you click one component and redirect you to another component which will render the countries, Yes?

Comment: thanks for your replay, added the landcard, and yes that is correct, i also guessed i have to make a new page for that as well, not sure about that.

Comment: Would you like to render countries In `LandCard`?

Comment: no, i would like to add more data to the countries add render them in a new component, lets say StateCard

Comment: So, You would like use `StateCard` in `LandCard`?

Comment: yes sorry if it seems confusing. so lets say: homepage+Landcard > than clicking EUROPE for example > than statepages+StateCard that shows us europe countries only. the hard part that i dont get is how to use StateCard for both USA and EUROPE.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, In your `HomePage` you have something like this:

```
 this.state.lands.map( ({ id, title}) => (
                <LandCard key={id} title={title} />
```

You could create a new component called `Routing`. In this component, we have something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from 'YOUR_HOME';
import StateCard from 'YOUR_STATE_CARD';

export const Routing = (props) => {
    return <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route component={Home} path="/"/>
            <Route component={StateCard} path=":/title"/>
        </Switch>
 </Router>
}
```

Your `LandCard` will same as past, it doesn't change. So with clicking on landing, it should redirect to your `StateCard` component. In addition in your `StateCard` you have :

```
 import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
 import {DATA} from 'YOUR_DATA'

 const StateCard(()=>{
 const { title } = useParams();
 const selectedData = DATA.countries.find((d) => d.title === title);
 return <div>
  {selectedData &&
    selectedData.countries.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <h2> {item.country} </h2>
        </div>
      );
    })}
</div>
});
```

Finally, Your `App` Component should transform to this:

```
export const App = () {
   return (
     <>
        <Routing/>
     </>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @barakooren Did this approach solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact={true} path={'/:continent?'}>
    <HomePage />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

and in `HomePage` component

```
const { continent } = useParams();
```

and then switch based on the `continent` variable.

Comment: guys im kinda missing something, how to do i use Route with something clickable?

Comment: @barakooren What exactly do you mean by using Route with something clickable?

Comment: @MajidMohammadi i took the code you gave me, added to the div on LandCard: onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}${title}`)} . on clicking the div this takes me to http://localhost:3000/USA or europe. depends what you click. when you get inside this URL there is nothing there, for some reason it doesnt take the "component={StateCard}" any ideas?

Comment: @barakooren actually you would like to click on `LandCard` and then redirect to `USA` or `Europe`? But I understood something else from your description!

Comment: @MajidMohammadi yes my friends sorry for the confusion... what you just wrote is what im trying to do. render 2 landcards (europe and usa) and when you click one of them it shows you the correct countries of usa or europe

Comment: @barakooren I updated my code, please look it again.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi got it, i really thank you for your time and will to help!!! thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

#### Defining routes

First, you need to define the routes such as:

```
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/:title" component={List} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

#### useParams

Then you can access `title` from the List component:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const { title } = useParams();
```

#### Filtering

Lastly, you can filter the state and render accordingly:

```
 const { title } = useParams();
 const selectedContinent = this.state.lands.find((d) => d.title === title);

 return <div>
      {selectedContinent &&
        selectedContinent.countries.map((item, index) => {
          console.log("item", item);
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <h2> {item.country} </h2>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
```